# Visual Studio 2022 on Mac Azure Devops Repository

Tags: c#, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022, azure-repos

I've moved from Visual Studio 2019 on Mac to 2022. I was able to easily connect to azure devops repos; however, for Visual Studio on Mac 2022 I can't seem to figure out to do it. All the Microsoft Visual Studio documentation seems to refer to 2019(Version Control menu)

Answer (score 2):

I actually just figured this out, and it was painful.  Here are the steps I did for Visual Studio 2022 17.3 for the Mac:

1. Go to your project in the web browser, i.e. https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projectname.
2. Click on Repos in the left navigation.
3. Click on Branches in the left navigation.
4. Click on the branch name (i.e. "master")
5. Click on the “Clone” button on the far right.
6. Click the “Clone in VS Code” button on the right pop out.
7. Copy the "real" URL you need from the query string in the browser, i.e. https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_git/myproject.
8. In Visual Studio on the Mac, click Git…Clone Repository.
9. Paste in the "real" URL from above.
10. It should let you pick an account you want to use (that you’ve set up in Visual Studio).  Alternatively you can enter a username and password.

From there you should be golden.

Comment: I didn't realize someone responded to this. This worked for me. Thanks!